# Controller not getting inputs laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, controller

Currently I am trying to pass a creation form to a controller. I have the route and the ajax call setup and talking to the route. My problem is that when I use the ajax call the inspect tool for headers is showing my form values correctly but when I go into the controller the request->input doesnt show any values for the form.

Here is my ajax call

```
$(document).on("click", ".form-submit-btn", function() {
    // Get the form id.
    var formID = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
    var serializedForm = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
    var substringEnd = formID.indexOf("-form");
    var route = formID.substr(0, substringEnd).replace("-", "_");

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    // Submit the form.
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/" + route,
        data: {
            serializedForm
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my controller

```
// Create Role
public function create(Request $request)
{
    // Get and validate request params
    $role = $request->input('role_name');
    $active = $request->input('role-active', false);

    return $role;
}
```

And here is my route

```
Route::post('/create_role', 'RoleController@create');
```

Am I missing something that is preventing the ajax call from sending the values to the controller

Here is my form also if that helps.

```
<form id="create-role-form" class="form">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<button class="pull-right right-close-btn">X</button>
<h1>Add Role</h1>
<hr />
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Role Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="role_name" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="role_active" value="true" checked /> Active
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control form-submit-btn">Create</button>
</div>
```

Comment: check print_r($request->serializedForm) in your controller and find whether data is avail or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is this line

```
data: {serializedForm},
```

Just change it to

```
data: serializedForm,
```

and it should fix the problem.

**Problems**

I see two problems with your `ajax` request

1. Are you sure you're using ES-6 TransPiler because `data:{serializedForm},` is ES-6 Syntax http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand
2. If you're javascript is working fine. You should be able to get it like `$request->get('serializedForm')['role_name']` with your existing code.

Hope it helps

Comment: That brackets were the problem, thank you I'm not used to serializing the form and sending it in usually just hand code the inputs in the data as an array.